# CursorAdapter works slow on android 4

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-cursoradapter

I have an extended CursorAdapter class that completes a suggestion list with data from my sqlite database. So far with android 2.3 used to work fine, but now in android 4.0.1 feels very slow. Another thing, secondly, is that the suggestion list scrolls very slow as well. Is there any known issue with the CursorAdapter in Ice Cream Sandwich? Tested on Nexus S device.

Edit:

I changed my approach and tried to use CursorLoader but still takes ages to run the query and fill my autocompleted list.

onCreate:

```
mSuggestionAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null,
            new String[] { "name_en", "pcode" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);
    search_text.setAdapter(mSuggestionAdapter);

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

onTextChanged:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MapActivity.this);
        }
```

CursorLoader Interface:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Uri baseUri = SearchableProvider.CONTENT_URI;

    String select = DataBaseHelper.getWhereStatement(search_text.getText().toString());
    return new CursorLoader(this, baseUri,
            DataBaseHelper.SEARCHABLE_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
            "name_en" );

    //return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSuggestionAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSuggestionAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Tried the same with ArrayAdapter as well. I get the data after some time (20-maybe30 seconds), but the list from the autocomplete Textview does not come up.

**The delay is between onCreateLoader (returns CursorLoader asynchronously) and onLoadFinished().**

Comment: http://greendao-orm.com/2011/12/17/sql-performance-in-android-4-0/

Comment: Note: I am using fts3 sqlite table

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` has been deprecated because of same reasons. Google recommends to use `CursorLoader` instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter` for better speed. `ArrayAdapter` is also a good idea.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Please check my edited answer above. Am I doing something wrong or misinterpret your answer?

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter is not deprecated and loaders and adapters are two completely different things...